# Script won't stop cleanly

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu-12.04

I wrote this small shell script to start a gunicorn WSGI server for my django app.  I'm running it on Ubuntu 12.04, and the script starts cleanly and runs like it's supposed to.  The problem is that the script and gunicorn continues to run even after <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  -<kbd>C</kbd>, i.e. it doesn't return to the prompt.

Why would this be, and how can I fix it?

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
NUM_WORKERS=3
cd /path/to/my/project
source ../bin/activate

gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS
```

Comment: Same problem: [Can't terminate gunicorn_django via Ctrl-C when invoked from a makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9857344). My guess: Aborting on Ctrl-C is entirely optional. Since the the behavior is inconsistent, it's probably a bug.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7959977/114147. Please try and do a search next time :-)

Comment: @wez That's really not a good solution to this question. I've submitted it to gunicorn's github and they've submitted a bug fix.  I'll test it out soon and see if it fixes anything.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to start server processes is to have them run in the background. E.g.

```
gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS &
```

The usual way to stop servers is to send them a signal, often the server process or the script that starts it, saves it's process-ID into a file so that your stop script can do something like

```
kill pid
```

See typical examples in `/etc/initd.d` scripts.

Comment: I also tried starting/stopping this script with upstart. gunicorn_django won't stop cleanly there either.

Comment: `killall gunicorn` ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/356) is the bug fix.  After doing a clean install with that branch it seems to work fine.